# Renaming of IPA app name

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have production IPA file with the name as MyApp. I need to change this name as MyApp_SIT for testing purpose. Where I have to do the modifications. I have the production IPA file and the new Provisioning profile and certificate for testing purpose. Is this possible to rename the app name. I have to finish it urgently. Can anyone please tell how to do this.

Comment: Change your bundle name from info.plist file.

Comment: Open the info.plist and change bundle name.

Comment: @aBilal17 you are telling about CFBundleDisplayName or CFBundleName. I already tried by by changing the CFBundleDisplayName but the app is not getting installed in device.

Comment: Check image in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the provisioning profile, certificate, and key, you can modify the .app payload contents and then re-sign.  But given that you do not have the source code, I doubt you have those.  If you do, here are the steps:

From the terminal:

```
unzip app.ipa

rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Payload/MyApp.app/Info.plist
```

Inside the PlistBuddy editor, do the following:

```
Set :CFBundleName MyApp_SIT
save
quit
```

Then, back at the command line, we resign the app with it's new bundle name:

```
cp <path_to_provisioing_profile>/AdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision 

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company Certificate" --resource-rules Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist  Payload/MyApp.app

zip -qr app-resigned.ipa Payload/
```

General steps referenced here:

https://coderwall.com/p/qwqpnw/resign-ipa-with-new-cfbundleidentifier-and-certificate

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on it. Can you please provide some easy commands to resign the .ipa file?

Comment: You use the commands in the answer above.  If that's too complicated, you could try iResign - https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 8 onwards simply changing Scheme name does the job , now .
Just go to scheme manager and first select the scheme and then it enter , whatever name you put that would be the name of ipa and app file.

Answer (score 1):

Check it. just change selected one.[image]

Comment: I am using text editor to see the properties of the info.plist file. I dont have any other tools like xcode. so can you tell the exact property name of the bundle name in info.plist so that I can change it and resign using the terminal. Please excuse me i am new to this technology.

Comment: Its showing same as "Bundle name", let me check it on my side

Comment: you have to change that name and recompile the code and create the ipa file again, you can not change the ipa file man.

Comment: I have only the production IPA file, I do not have the code. So it is not possible to rename the app name?

Comment: Ask the developer to change the name of app for you,

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify an `.ipa`, but you can recompile it if you have the source code.

Simply go in your `info.plist` file and change the `Bundle Display Name` key. If it's not there you can add it yourself.

That key is the name that will appear under the icon of your app. The user will see a different name even though your bundle name/project name are still the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible , Because if extract plist file from ipa and try to modify it then it will be not work .