# Change the IPA name or Archive name dynamically when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, archive, ipa

Is there a way to change dynamically the name of the archives when it finishes to compiling without adding it manually like I do now (with a script for example). I would like to add the version after each archiving in suffix to the name of the app, for example :

[image]

The command lines in the terminal doesn't interest me as it takes more time to do it by command than just adding 4 characters manually (cf [Renaming of IPA app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370320/renaming-of-ipa-app-name) or [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)) like this:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}”
```

My goal is to have an ipa with the name of the app, and the version **with Xcode**.

Thanks.